# Create a chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I want to create a graph that looks like the one mentioned in the below image. For sample graph, please visit 
http://i29.tinypic.com/2r3w3o2.png

How can I create a chart like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, in SSRS 2005 (I don't know about later versions), since you can't combine multiple different chart types (here, stacked bar and line charts) on the same chart. You *could* implement this as two separate charts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible in ssrs 2008. The term to search on is "multiple Y axis" or "using a secondary axis" for ssrs 2005 without a 3rd party plugin like Dundas you are out of luck.